# Java simple date formatter for string to date

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

Can anyone point out what seems to be the problem here?

```
try {
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("Mon, 02 Nov 2015 15:13:00 EET").parse("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss z");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and the stacktrace:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon, 02 Nov 2015 15:13:00 EET" (at offset 26)
```

I'm suspecting something with the locale that I'm using but I can't be sure. Seems that "z" for timezone not working.

Edit:
Sorry the exception was funny earlier, I changed it but forgot to update here.

```
try {
            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss z", Locale.US).parse("Mon, 02 Nov 2015 15:13:00 EET");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: You have the arguments backwards. pass the format string to SimpleDateFormat contructor and the actual date string to parse

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to update the code earlier, here's the real one with that exception. The old one was giving some kinda funny exception like "no pattern 'o' " or something

Comment: next guess would be that EET is not a recognized timezone

Comment: What I meant is that I get the unparseable date exception with the right order

Comment: Have you tried with `Locale.ENGLISH` ? what is the `Locale` in your system ? The string is parsed into a date just fine in my system

Comment: Yea no luck. Would it matter? My time zone is GMT but isn't this some kinda global thing?

Answer (score 1):

After looking at javadoc for SimpleDateFormat, you are using "hh" for hour, which is assumed to be a 12-hour time.  Use HH for 24-hour time.  Your example as 15 for the hour.

Comment: Yea I changed that one, thank you for declaring but that's not the problem. I think when you use hh it mods your value since the problem is at offset 26, and it still is after i changed it to HH.

Comment: Then I'm back to the timezone EET not being recognized by Java, even if it's a valid timezone.  Try replacing EET with EST.

Comment: Yea seems its working with EST. Too bad it's a feed and can't change it. Guess I'll split and hope that feed won't change. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing 'z' here.

Try:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("Mon, 02 Nov 2015 15:13:00 EET").
        parse("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz")
```

Since your timezone is with three characters.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. In oracle documentation they gave this example "K:mm a, z" 0:08 PM, PDT. But not that it matters, I tried every combination from 1 to 4 z just to make sure earlier capital or lower :)

Answer (score 0):

Such an exception can come from parsing a date with the wrong Locale. For example this date formatter :

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss z", Locale.US);
```

will successfully parse the example date :

```
Date date = df.parse("Mon, 02 Nov 2015 15:13:00 EET");
```

But the following will give the exception you are getting

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss z", Locale.FRENCH);
```

I would expect the Locale in Android to be chosen according to the language set by the user.

Comment: But I'm already creating the simpleDateFormatter instance with Locale.US, would it not be the case to use Locale.getDefault() to get the exception?